# When is $\sqrt{k}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\operatorname{Var}(X_{i}) $ true?

Tags: probability, inequality, variance, covariance

Assume we have $k$ dependent random variables $X_{1}, \dots, X_{k}$ with $\operatorname{Var}(X_{i}) < \infty$.

In which case

$$\sqrt{k}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\operatorname{Var}(X_{i})\,? 
$$

It seems that negative covariance is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the identity
$$\operatorname{Var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{Var}(X_i) + \sum_{i > j} 2\operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_j)$$
we can see why having negative covariance isn't sufficient; we need the covariances to be negative *enough* to offset the $\sqrt k$ multiplier. Specifically, what we need is

\begin{align*}
  & \sqrt k\sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{Var}(X_i) + \sqrt k \sum_{i > j} 2\operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_j) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{Var}(X_i) \\
\iff & \sum_{i > j} \operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_j) \leq \frac{k^{-1/2} - 1}{2 } \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{Var}(X_i)
\end{align*}
and we note that the coefficient on the right is always negative when $k \geq 2$, implying that having negative total covariances is necessary but not sufficient.